# PostgreSQL Table Partitioning using monthwise

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

I am creating a shell script to import PostgreSQL logs into a table using month-wise partitioning.

I am trying to create a function `log_insert` with `$DATE` parameter.

The function is created successfully and logs are imported into respective month tables when i  hard-code the table name `postgres_log_jun`:

```
 CREATE LANGUAGE plpgsql;
 create or replace function logs_insert() returns trigger as $$
 declare
 begin
    if ( new.log_time >= date_trunc('month', current_date) and new.log_time <= date_trunc('month',current_date)+'1month'::interval-'1day'::interval) then
    insert into postgres_log_jun values (new.*); 
else
    raise exception 'log_time date out of range';
end if;
return null;
end;
$$ language plpgsql;
```

But same i am trying after declaring the date variable where:

```
EXPORT DATE=$(date +%^b)
EXPORT DATABASE=demo
psql -d $DATABASE << 'EOF'
CREATE LANGUAGE plpgsql;
create or replace function logs_insert() returns trigger as $$
declare
    tbl_var text := 'postgres_log_$DATE';
begin
    if ( new.log_time >= date_trunc('month', current_date) and new.log_time <= date_trunc('month',current_date)+'1month'::interval-'1day'::interval) then
    EXECUTE'
       insert into ' || quote_ident(tbl_var) || ' values ' (new.*);
else 
    raise exception 'log_time date out of range';
end if;
return null;
end;
$$ language plpgsql;"
EOF
```

However, this is not working.

Can someone help me resolve this?

Thank you for your support.

Comment: Please explain how "*this is not working*". What is the actual vs expected behavior?

Comment: When i try to to create function it show below 
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "("
LINE 7: ...insert into ' || quote_ident(tbl_var) || ' values ' (new.*);
                                                               ^
ERROR:  unterminated quoted identifier at or near """
LINE 1: "
        ^

Comment: don't you miss a `||` after `' values '`? Or shouldn't it be `' values (new.*)'`?

Comment: @added comment in answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
DATE=$(date +%^b)
DATABASE=demo3
psql -d $DATABASE << EOF
   create or replace function logs_insert() returns trigger as \$\$
declare
   tbl_var text := 'postgres_log_$DATE';
   qry text;
begin
      if ( new.log_time >= date_trunc('month', current_date) and new.log_time <= date_trunc('month',current_date)+'1month'::interval-'1day'::interval) then
           qry := ' insert into ' || quote_ident(tbl_var) ||  ' SELECT (\$1).*';
           execute qry USING NEW;
     else
           raise exception 'log_time date out of range';
     end if;

    return null;
    end;
  \$\$ language plpgsql;
EOF
```

Answer (score 0):

```
declare
tbl_var text := 'postgres_log_$date';
qry text;
begin
    if ( new.log_time >= date_trunc('month', current_date) and new.log_time <= date_trunc('month',current_date)+'1month'::interval-'1day'::interval) then
         qry := ' insert into ' || quote_ident(tbl_var) ||  ' SELECT ($1).*';
         execute qry USING NEW;
    else
        raise exception 'log_time date out of range';
    end if;

    return null;
end;
```

This is perfect answer, now its working for me....Thanks @Rafalon for your support...